# Configuring the expiry time for the messages destined to the "Expired message address" in Hornetq

Tags: java, jms, hornetq

I have configured a message expiry destination in Hornetq as below

```
<address-setting match="#">
      <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.error</dead-letter-address>
      <expiry-address>jms.queue.error</expiry-address>
         <max-delivery-attempts>3</max-delivery-attempts>
      <redelivery-delay>2000</redelivery-delay>
      <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>       
      <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
      <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
      <redistribution-delay>60000</redistribution-delay>
</address-setting>
```

And the messages do get redirected to the expiry address once the expiration time is exceeded. These messages live indefinitely on the expiry address, Is there a way to provide a expiry time for these messages so they live only limited time on the expiry address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using at least 2.3, you could create a setting for the expiry itself, with a delay, without specifying the expiry-address:

```
   <address-setting match="jms.queue.error">
         <dead-letter-address>ExpiryOfExpiry</dead-letter-address>
         <expiry-address>ExpiryOfExpiry</expiry-address>
         <max-delivery-attempts>3</max-delivery-attempts>
         <expiry-delay>3600000</expiry-delay> <!-- one hour... or use whatever you want -->
         <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>       
         <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
         <redistribution-delay>60000</redistribution-delay>
    </address-setting>
```

ExpiryOfExpiry will be an empty address.. so the message will just be sent to nobody. it will be acked on the Address and then be removed.

We don't have a test for this scenario but it should work. Let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: Were you able to test my answer? I would appreciate the accpetance if you did. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am currently caught up on different assignment. I will test out this solution in couple of days and surely update the results here.